# Cannot complete batch file

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

```
:LOOP    
:: Finds Removable Disk Letter
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, description') do if "%%b %%c"=="Removable Disk" set drive=%%a&goto COPY
:COPY
xcopy %drive% D:\Backup
goto :LOOP
```

I have no such experience in batch and I want to know, how can I do following? :
if removable disk not exist, do not go to COPY and go to LOOP ?

Comment: Do you only need to omit "Removable Disk" drives? Would you also like to omit "CD-ROM Disc" drives? What are you trying to do essentially?

Answer (score 1):

Just let `wmic` do the filtering for you:

```
:LOOP
for /f %%d in (
  'wmic logicaldisk where description^="Removable Disk" get caption ^| find ":"'
) do (
  xcopy %%d D:\Backup
)
goto LOOP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:LOOP    
:: Finds Removable Disk Letter
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, description') do (
if "%%b %%c"=="Removable Disk" set drive=%%a
if not exist "%%a" goto :LOOP
)
:COPY
xcopy %drive% D:\Backup
goto :LOOP
```

Basically, if the drive doesn't exist it will go back to `:LOOP`, if it does it will automatically fall through to `:COPY`.

Comment: and.. it is not possible to skip
:COPY
?
not automati ally fall through